# How to Remove Old NuGet Packages

Tags: nuget

I am using the public NuGet server and when I click at the solution and Manage Nuget Packages I can see a number of packages which are older versions of packages that are also installed. When I click "Manage" I can see the older package is not installed on any project in my solution but I do not get the option of removing it. Meanwhile the latest package is installed on a number of projects and is being referenced and used just fine.

Answer (score 5):

The NuGet.org website doesn't provide a way to remove a package that's been posted.  The reason is that we don't want to accidentally break any existing projects that may be using the older version, or force existing users to upgrade their packages.

We do understand that there are special circumstances and reasons to make an exception to this rule, though.  If you need an old package to be removed, you can drop us a line using the "Report Abuse" form on the website with the reason you need the package to be removed, and one of the site's administrators will review it.